# Font Awesome icons not displaying on the VPN

Tags: css, font-awesome

I just noticed that Font-Awesome icons are not displaying when the users access my website via VPN.

If they are accessing the website onsite, everything's working fine and they work perfectly.

The same problem doesn't occur for other JQuery and Bootstrap CDNs even if they are on the same page and access via VPN.  This problem occurs only for Font-Awesome css.  I have tried with both Javascript and CSS version and both give me a same error.  It happens on all browsers too.

My VPN changes the links to

```
<link href="https://portal.mysite.ac.uk/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/,DanaInfo=code.jquery.com,CT=css+jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="https://portal.mysite.ac.uk/,DanaInfo=use.fontawesome.com,SSL+4b650a8101.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And it shows me an error in the browser as below:

[image]

So, if you guys ever encountered this kind of problem, could you please let me know how we can get around it?

Here is the example of my FA usage:

```
<a title="View Application" class="fa fa-folder-open-o" href="/Application/AssessmentDetail/,DanaInfo=sea+10040"></a>
```

Is there a way to show 'title' if the loading of FontAwesome fails?

Comment: Why don't you simply host them locally rather than over a CDN? This way if they can load your site to begin with, they'll be able to load any other files hosted on your site.

Comment: Yeah, I might as well host it on site if there is no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues. What I had to do was connect to a location that supports port forwarding. Once I did, all the icons started working.